# How to simulate the behaviour when the user loads the app from the URL in the browser's address bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutter-web-browser

I'm writing a Flutter web application and I want to write a test on the behavior when the user loads the app when he types the URL in the browser's address bar.
For example I would like my test to behave as if the user typed `/my/path`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the class [`PlatformDispatcher`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher-class.html) (which olds a singleton instance `.instance`) you can see a getter [`defaultRouteName`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher/defaultRouteName.html).

> The route or path that the embedder requested when the application was launched.
>
> This will be the string "`/`" if no particular route was requested.

So when your user starts your application with the url `/my/path`, `PlatformDispatcher.instance.defaultRouteName` with be equal to `'/my/path'`.

---

### How to mock it?

You can also access the `PlatformDispatcher.instance` from `WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher` and if you read the doc of the getter [`platformDispatcher`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/BindingBase/platformDispatcher.html), you'll read:

> A subclass of `BindingBase`, such as `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding`, can override this accessor to return a different `ui.PlatformDispatcher` implementation.

In the context of a `testWidgets`

```dart
testWidgets('', (WidgetTester test) async {});
```

`tester.binding` gives you access to the [`TestWidgetsFlutterBinding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestWidgetsFlutterBinding-class.html) which is the binding used by widgets library tests. In this test binding, the `platformDispatcher` is overridden and a [`TestPlatformDispatcher`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestPlatformDispatcher-class.html) with a setter [`defaultRouterNameTestValue`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestPlatformDispatcher/defaultRouteNameTestValue.html) that you can use to mock the `defaultRouteName` getter.

### TL;DR

You can use:

```dart
tester.binding.platformDispatcher.defaultRouteNameTestValue = '/my/path'
```

to test the behavior when the user loads the app when he types the URL `/my/path` in the browser's address bar.